# Does running a sensitive application in tmpfs provides enough protection against application theft in my use case?

Tags: network, linux, c++

I am thinking of running my C++ Linux application via a mounted tmpfs. The idea is to have application client running in the embedded Linux platform and  download the main application from a secure server into tmpfs with its necessary files and execute it. The secure server is running in the same premises as the embedded Linux device and powered by a lithium battery. The main idea if someone removed the device from the premises and tampered with it, the device will power cycle trigger by a sensor. If the device was stolen from the premises, the server will blacklist it. My question is whether this will be robust to make sure that the critical files not fall into the wrong hands. Should I be considering encrypting the SD card?

Comment: Hi! It looks like the real question is in the scope of "tmpfs vs removable driver" choice from the point of cybersecurity. I believe it's worth to change the title to such which reflects the real question. Stackoverflow recommendation about  the title: "Bad: [php] session doubt, Good: How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?"

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do the impossible. If the attacker has physical access to both the embedded Linux platform and the secure server, which it sounds like they do since they're "in the same premises", you lose.

Comment: ... If you have a server secure enough to distribute the application, why isn't it secure enough to _run_ it?

Comment: Sorry I should be a bit more specific. The device will be used by the customer and potentially it could be remove from the premises (theft). If the person was a hacker or have some considerable knowledge in reverse engineering, I want to ensure the main application and files are wiped out hence why downloading and running it in tmpfs. And reset the device when tampered with so the main files are wiped out as the application is stored and running in ram.

Comment: ... no, what I was getting at was, could you make the server run everything, and the client device be essentially a dumb terminal?  For that matter, do you even need a secure client device - could whatever this is be displayed on a device the customer brings with them (like a phone)?  What is this application doing that you feel the need to do this kind of security in the first place?  What are the user devices doing that you feel you need a C++ app?  And what form factor are these devices - can they just be locked in a cabinet?

Comment: The embedded device will be running AI models. It is the AI models that is the IP. It is high throughput image processing in the device. The application is a smart trolley. The reason for C++ is speed, and trolley/carts are usually stolen from the store hence the security.